# Convert .Net Bitmap() to MagickImage

Tags: imagemagick

An upgrade from ImageMagick 7.17 to 7.22.2.1 NuGet results in the following error on the constructor of a MagickImage. I can't put my finger on the replacement methods. Help me locate the documentation. Thank you,

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[]'

Code:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(somesource);
var m = new MagickImage(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitmap reader was moved to Magic.NET.SystemDrawing.

```
var m = new MagickFactory();
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(m.Image.Create(objImage));
```

Comment: Hi Hintz. Is this a solution? I don't get it.

Comment: This doesn't work - m.Image.Create does not accept a parameter of type Bitmap

Comment: You need to install this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET.SystemDrawing/ along with the other standard package for this to work.Refer https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/619

Answer (score 2):

I've only just started playing with this, so this may not be great code, but it has worked for me so far.

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this IMagickImage mimg, MagickFormat fmt = MagickFormat.Png24)
{
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mimg.Write(ms, fmt);
        ms.Position = 0;
        bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
    }
    return bmp;
}
public static IMagickImage ToMagickImage(this Bitmap bmp)
{
    IMagickImage img = null;
    MagickFactory f = new MagickFactory();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Position = 0;
        img = new MagickImage(f.Image.Create(ms));
    }
    return img;
}
```

Some ImageMagick operations seem to require a different format when writing to the stream, so you may need to play with the `fmt` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using both answers to use my bitmaps with [MagickImageCollection()](https://csharpdoc.hotexamples.com/class/ImageMagick/MagickImageCollection).

```cs
using var collection = new MagickImageCollection();

for(var frame = 0; frame < _animation.Length; frame++) {
    Bitmap        bitmap        = _animation[frame];
    Bitmap        canvas        = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    MagickFactory magickFactory = new MagickFactory();

    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using Graphics     graphics     = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);

    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));

    canvas.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    canvas.Dispose();

    collection.Add(new MagickImage(magickFactory.Image.Create((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(memoryStream))));
    collection[frame].AnimationDelay = 100;

    memoryStream.Close();
}

collection.Quantize(new QuantizeSettings { Colors = 256 });
collection.Write(dialog.FileName);
collection.Dispose();
```

I should note that I am using [Magick.NET.SystemDrawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET.SystemDrawing) v4.0.19 and [Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU) v11.0.0 in this project. I hope this helps for future readers.